# Alternative to Nesting forEach

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, newArr contains my form input names in camel case and inputList contains the form input names in HTML.

I wish to iterate over both and have newArr entries be my keys and the values inputted into the form inputs be my value.

I then want to use these key value pairs to change states.

Here is my attempt

```js
newArr.forEach(entry => {
  let key = entry;
  console.log(key);
  inputList.forEach(entry => {
    let val = document.getElementById(entry).value;
    this.setState({
      [key]: val
    });
    console.log(val);
  })
```

This changes the state of all my keys to the value of the last value created from inputList.

Is there a better way of doing this and if not how could I change my code to work as intended.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the name `entry` twice?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you add `array` and expected result.

Comment: Are the two arrays always going to be the same length?

Comment: Yes @sychordCoder, both arrays are created from form inputs and should always be the same length. I want the variable 'key' to be the names of the state and 'val' to be what the user inputs into those forms.

Comment: I would suggest you do not use two arrays, but rather an object that maps a state name to a html name.

Comment: I see setState so it seems like you are working with react. Are you managing state of form values using DOM methods?

Comment: You should probably be storing these in objects as Bergi stated. But if you want to use the arrays the issue here is you are cycling through every inputList value for every key value. Since both arrays are the same length, you could do a simple For loop and assign the key value pairs like that and use the iterator to index both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is almost pretty good, I highly recommend you avoid the nested forEach and very important to avoid use `this.setState` into forEach, remember each time you iterate over array you are update your component, so if you have more children into your component that will affect your React tree performance, so I suggest the following, based that the you need the `key` in the same order (index), so you can use reduce to loop over keys array and generate the nextState to just update the component once instead of multiple times.

```
const nextState = newArr.reduce((state, key, index) => {
  const inputId = inputList[index];
  const input = document.getElementById(inputId);
  if (!input) {
    // avoid error by try getting value from undefined input
    return state;
  }
  const value = input.value;
  return { ...state, [key]: value };
}, {});

this.setState(nextState);
```

Doing that way, you avoid cuadratic loops and avoid updating react components for each loop, so you are batching the updates into one, that's better.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

All of your keys are being paired to the last element of inputList because the inner forEach is running through the entire inputList, and the val is being updated each time. *Replacing document.getElementById with f(x)*, the execution really looks like this:

```
newArr[0]: f(inputList[0])
newArr[0]: f(inputList[1])
...
newArr[0]: f(inputList[n]) (n being the nth (last) element)
...
newArr[n]: f(inputList[0])
...
newArr[n]: f(inputList[n])
```

If you need state to contain:

```
newArr[0]: f(inputList[0])
newArr[1]: f(inputList[1])
...
newArr[n]: f(inputList[n])
```

The following will create a 1:1 mapping between items in newArr and inputList.

**Snazzy JS function**

```
newArr.map(function(key, index) {
  let entry = inputList[index]
  let val = document.getElementById(entry).value;
  this.setState({key: val});
});
```

**Mapping each newArr item to the entire inputList**

If you need to map each item in newArr with all items in inputList, this will do just that:

```
inputList.map(val => {
  document.getElementById(val).value;
});

newArr.forEach(item => {
  this.setState({item: inputList})
});
```

This will set state as the following:

```
newArr[0] = [f(inputList[0]), f(inputList[1]), ..., f(inputList[n])]
...
newArr[n] = [f(inputList[0]), f(inputList[1]), ..., f(inputList[n])]
```

***That being said, if possible, create {key:val} objects when collecting the values rather than arrays in the first place. This way you can just directly set state.***